# Update Option of Theano Function

Tags: theano

I am using the theano tutorials of deep learning and I have a doubt regarding how the **theano function's update** works. Whatever parameters the update is defined with will it take the new value if any of the parameters changed?

```
theano.function( [i],
                 cost,
                 updates = updates,
                 givens = { self.x: trainX[i*self.mbSize: (i+1)*self.mbSize],
                            self.y: trainY[i*self.mbSize: (i+1)*self.mbSize]
                          }
               )
```

Updates is defined as

```
updates = [ (param, param-learnRate*grad)
                    for param, grad in zip(self.params, gradients) ]
```

Here learnRate is not a theano variable. My question is if I change the learnRate at some point of time  then will the theano function  take the changed value of learnRate or will continue with the old value?

LearnRate is changed as

```
LearnRate = LearnRate/10
```

Initially the LearnRate was 0.05

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will continue with the old value.

Numbers are immutable in python so changing the value of `LearnRate` won't affect the value being used in the `updates` list, and I guess once a theano function is compiled with the provided `updates` it can not be changed unless you compile it again with the new value.

As you probably have known, you can make the learning rate a theano variable and then change its value when you want to.

Here's another question that might be useful, [Is there a way to change a function's update list without re-compiling it in Theano?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34146656/is-there-a-way-to-change-a-functions-update-list-without-re-compiling-it-in-the)